# Hibernate audits to update time in the main table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a product and it has relation tables(ex: category). When we modify anything on the relation table. The audit listener is not updating the product updated time. I have entity listeners but it is only updating when we update the data in the product table.

```
@EntityListeners(value = AuditListener.class)
```

How I can achieve this?

Thanks , in advance.
Sri.